# make pdf from html code(which is on another component) in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf, jspdf

I have a component say parentComponent and it has a button downloadPDF and when I click on this button I want to download pdf from HTML code of another component say childComponent without showing it on the screen.

I had done it but it is showing the HTML code of childComponent on the screen.
the thing I don't want to.

my code of childComponent is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: '<div id="pdfData">this is small html code mine is big one</div>',
  styleUrls: ['./childComponent.component.css']
})
export class childComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }
  generatePDFChild() {
    const elementToPrint = document.getElementById('pdfData');
    const pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addHTML(elementToPrint, () => {
      pdf.save('test.pdf');
    });

  }
```

parentComponent in which contains downloadButton:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: '<app-child></app-child><a (click)="generatePDFParent()">Download PDF</a>',
  styleUrls: ['./parentComponent.component.css']
})

export class parentComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild(childComponent)
  private childComponentParent: childComponent;
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() { }
generatePDFParent() {

     this.childComponentParent.generatePDFChild();

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem now, what's your solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the code is you have added the child component selector  in the parent component.

if you don't want to display the content at any time.  hide the div tag by using CSS as `display:none`  or hide it before you generate the pdf;

```
generatePDFChild() {
    const elementToPrint = document.getElementById('pdfData');
    const pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addHTML(elementToPrint, () => {
      pdf.save('test.pdf');
    })
elementToPrint .style.display="none"
}
```

Comment: If i remove the child component selector then parent can't access the function generatePDF of child.

Comment: you can hide the element once you pass the data to pdf;

Comment: Pradeep I want it to be hide all time.